# Deleting current row jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, selected

I'm trying to delete a table row using jQuery. I used all the methods I could find and none work.
I have a  delete  on the end of each row and when I click it I trigger a function which should delete the row where it is located. But it just won't work.

In the comments are my tries which failed.
Is there a pseudo like first but for the current item (something like this) ?

```
function del(){

//$(this).parent().parent().remove();
//$(this).closest("tr").remove();
//$('table tr:last').remove();   this one worked but it deletes the last and I want the current one to be deleted

 }
```

Here is the code that generates the table:

```
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
var ttr = $("<tr class='rou' />");   
$.each(data, function(k, v){
var store_1 = v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100);
var xstore_1 = store_1.toFixed(2);

$("<td class='teedee'></td>").text(k=='name' ? v : xstore_1).appendTo(ttr);



});
$("<td id='delete' onClick='del();'>Delete</td>").appendTo(ttr);
$("#tejbl").append(ttr);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).closest("tr").remove();` will work just fine if you change the HTML to use `onClick='del(this);'`. Even better would be to skip the ugly DOM0 event binding and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.delete', del);
```

Note that your code is currently generating HTML with duplicate IDs, which is bad-bad-bad. Element IDs must be unique. Use classes instead:

```
$("<td class='delete'>Delete</td>").appendTo(ttr);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. And thanks for the additional tips :)